# Maintaining a search-optimal tree

Tags: co.combinatorics

Here is a completely new reformulation of almost the same problem. I hope it is more attractive to mathematicians.

[new version]

A binary tree is either:

- a leaf, denoted by $\mathit{Leaf}$, or
- an internal node consisting of a pair $(L, R)$, where both $L$ and $R$ are binary trees; we shall call $L$ the left child of the node, and $R$ the right child of the node.

We say that a binary tree is *optimal* if the difference between its longest and shortest path (starting from the root to a leaf) is at most one. Where by a path of a tree $T$ we mean a sequence $\langle T = T_0, T_1, \dots, T_k = \mathit{Leaf} \rangle$, such that $T_{i+1}$ is either the left or right child of $T_i$.

Our game is parameterized by two natural numbers $N$ and $K$; its initial configuration is a pair $\langle N, \mathit{Leaf} \rangle$. The game consists of $2^K-1$ rounds. At each round:

- player *A* chooses a leaf from the tree and substitutes it with “the singleton internal node” $(\mathit{Leaf}, \mathit{Leaf})$, then
- player *B* chooses any node (either internal or a leaf) and substitutes it with any tree having the same number $M$ of leaves as the tree rooted at the chosen node; the number $N$ is substituted with $N – M + 1$.

If at the end of any round the tree is not *optimal*, or the number $N$ from the configuration is negative, player *A* wins. Otherwise, after $2^K-1$ rounds, player *B* wins.

Question: given $K$, for which $N$ does player $B$ have a wining strategy?

[new version]

---

The following question I asked on my very first course in Algorithms, just when I had started my studies. I am not interested in discrete mathematics that much anymore, but would be very delighted for any approximation of the answer (I have never got any).

---

[edit]A binary tree over alphabet $\Sigma$ is either:

- a leaf, or
- an internal node consisting of a triple $\langle L, \sigma, R\rangle$, where $\sigma \in \Sigma$ and both $L$ and $R$ are binary trees over $\Sigma$; we shall call $L$ the left subtree of the node, $R$ the right subtree of the node, and $\sigma$ an element of the node.

That is --- a binary tree over $\Sigma$ is an element of the free algebra over $X \mapsto 1 \sqcup X \times \Sigma \times X$. A binary search tree, is a binary tree over a linear order $\Sigma$, where for each node $\langle L, \sigma, R\rangle$ we have that $\sigma$ is no less than any element from its left subtree, and less than any element from its right subtree.[edit]

A binary search tree is *search-optimal* if the difference between its longest and shortest path (starting from the root to a leaf) is at most one.

[edit] This condition is much stronger than being an AVL tree. The height of a tree is the longest path from its root to one of its leaf. We say that a tree is AVL if at any node the difference between the heights of its left and right subtrees is at most one. For example Fibonacci trees are AVL, but may have arbitrary large difference between their longest and shortest path.
[edit]

A binary search tree is *perfect* if at any node the difference between the numbers of internal nodes in its left and right subtrees is at most one.

---

Our task will be to maintain search-optimal tree during consecutive insertions. We shall use maintenance strategies based on the concept of “partial rebuilding” --- that is whenever after insertion the tree is out of search-optimal shape, we choose one of its node, and rebuild the whole subtree rooted at that node to the perfect tree (the cost of this operation is equal to the number of nodes in the subtree).

What strategy has the best worst-case complexity, and what is its complexity?

[edit] A more mathematical version of the question. Suppose that we start from the empty tree and have to maintain it during $2^k-1$ insertions. The cost of rebuilding a subtree having $n$ nodes is $n$ euros. What strategy guarantees that we spend the smallest amount of euros in the worst-case?
[edit]

Notice that rebuilding a tree at the lowest possible node is not optimal --- for example in the following situation it is much better to rebuild the whole tree than its right subtree ([edit from the comment] the picture shows only internal nodes [edit]):

[image]

Comment: As far as I remember, the operations with binary search trees are described in Cormen "Introduction to algorithms".

Comment: I am pretty sure my question is not described in "Introduction to algorithms", and any other textbook.

Comment: The picture shows only *internal nodes* of the trees.

Answer (score 1):

See [this survey paper](https://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~morin/teaching/5408/refs/a99.pdf) for several types of binary tree balancing.  You will see things quite similar to your suggestions.  However, I'll also note that what you call "search optimal" is not much use as you define it since it applies to a tree which is a single path, or just two paths of equal length.

Comment: A single path is not a binary tree. I heve edited the question to remove further confusions. However, thank you for the paper, I will definitely look at it.

Comment: Brendan, this is a good expository paper on maintenance algorithms, but it does not tackle my question.

Comment: A single path is indeed a binary tree.  $A\to B\to C\to D$, root is $A$, each node is a child of the previous node.  It has only one leaf $D$ so your condition is satisfied.  Maybe you don't mean to ask what you actually wrote.

Comment: @Brendan: a single path is not a *binary* tree. Please, read the definition from my question more carefully, or consult your favorite textbook.

Comment: @Brendan: Maybe my picture caused confusion --- as I have written in a comment, the picture shows only *internal* nodes. Your path shows only internal nodes then it actually corresponds to the tree $A(0, B(0, C(0, D(0, 0))))$, and if these are all nodes, then it is not *binary*

Comment: @Michal: According to the definition of a binary search tree from Wikipedia, the tree $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4$ is a valid binary search tree. This definition does not forbid that the left or the right subtree is empty, it also does not imply any kind of balancing.

Comment: @Stanislav: Now, when you said that, I have checked wikipedia once more. I am really sorry, both you and Brendan are right. According to wiki a binary tree may have also *unary* nodes. This definition creates a lot of problems and confucions. Moreover, it is inconsistent with other pages (on balanced trees), where binary trees are not allowed to have unary nodes. I should not have linked to Wikipedia. Please, use my definition, or definitions from any "normal" textbooks :-)

Comment: BTW, wikipedia conradicts itself. The only "almost formal" definition of a binary tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Type_theory says that it is an initial (inductive/free) algebra of the functor $\alpha \mapsto 1 + A \times \alpha \times \alpha$ --- such a definition clearly forbids unary nodes, and is equivalent to the definition I have provided with my question.

Comment: @Michal: But your definition puts restrictions on the number of nodes. For example, your binary tree cannot contain 2 nodes. I find the definition from Wikipedia, which is also used in "Introduction to algorithms", more normal.

Comment: @Stanislav: sure, you cannot have a binary tree with exactly $2$ nodes, but that is not a problem --- we can have a tree with exactly $2$ *internal* nodes; we just do not care about leaves (which do not contain any information). I have never seen the definition from wiki in practice.

Comment: Another problem with that definition is that it is *inconvenient* --- compare: $\alpha \mapsto A + A \times \alpha + A \times \alpha \times \alpha$ to the above definition. The later does not even allow empty tries! If it allowed then it would be a question whether (for example) $(a, ())$ should be the same as $(a)$. If these were the same, then the definition of a tree would not be *inductive*. If not, then you have to carry this additional condition along every definition.

Comment: @Stanislav: I have checked "Introduction to algorithms" and they (informally) uses the same definition as mine.

Comment: Well, o.k., now I understand your definition. About practice: AVL and red-black trees seem to be most popular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-red-black-tree

Comment: Splay trees are popular in practice too, even though they only guarantee good performance in an amortized sense.

Answer (score 0):

<del>A binary tree of which every subtree is search-optimal is called an AVL tree (height-balanced tree).  Efficient algorithms for AVL trees are described in Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* chapter 6.2.3.  In particular, you can insert a new element in $ O(\log n) $ time where $ n $ is the number of elements in the tree.  Like Stanislav notes above, they are also described in Cormen–Leiserson–Rivest–Stein, *Introduction to Algorithms* second edition chapter 13-3.</del>

<del>For search, these and related structures are called balanced trees.</del>

Update: above is wrong, see comment of Michal R. Przybylek.

Comment: No, AVL trees generaly are not search-optimal. In AVL trees the difference between the longest and shortest path may be arbitrary large (see for example fibonacci trees).